# How to convert Vector of type Any to List of String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to cast  ((raw) Any!>..Vector<*>?) to List?

Trial 1

```
   val Result: List<String>?
   Result = ResultCreator.takeIf {
                shouldCreateResults()
            }?.resultVector()?.toList()
        )
```

Error:
Required List? found List<Any!>?

Trial 2:

```
   val Result: List<String>?
   Result = ResultCreator.takeIf {
                shouldCreateResults()
            }?.resultVector()?.map{ toString() }?.toList()
        )
```

Error:
Here toString() is returning object reference rather than the string value.

Any suggestion or advise will be helpful

Comment: What does `((raw) Any!>..Vector<*>?)` mean? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you mean `?.resultVector()?.map{ it.toString() }`?

Comment: That was the solution :( unfortunately very new to kotlin wasted way too much time on it thank you.